# How to increase radio button size using LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiogroup

I am trying to increase the size of `RadioButton` in `LinearLayout` which wraps into `ScrollView` but it is not working in any way. I tried to use property like `.setScaleX()` and `.setScaleY()` but it didn't work. Here is my code:

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">



    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:text="Current location: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="5sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_location"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:sca
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/zone_types_list_View"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/room_type_border"/>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**code to create radio button using radioGroup:**

```
private LinearLayout listView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  listView = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.zone_types_list_View);
}

private void addRadioButtons() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    radioGroup = new RadioGroup(mActivity);
                    for (String ss : typesList) {
                        radioButton = new RadioButton(mActivity);
                        radioButton.setText(ss);
                        radioButton.setTag(ss.trim());
                        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
                        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {
                                    String tag = (String) buttonView.getTag();
                                    Log.i(TAG, "selected radio: " + tag);
                                    submitZoneType(tag.trim());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
               /*     radioGroup.setPivotX(0);
                    radioGroup.setPivotY(0);

                    radioGroup.setScaleX(2f);
                    radioGroup.setScaleY(2f); */
                    listView.addView(radioGroup);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

If I add `radioGroup.setScaleX(2f)` dynamically, it helps me to increase the `RadioButton`s size but then rest of the `buttons` hide in the `layout` and scrolling not work. I am not understanding why scrolling is not working like this way. Is there any other way to increase the size of `RadioButtons`?

Comment: Could you check myanswer?@user565

Answer (score 1):

its Worked

```
radioButton.setHeight(10);
radioButton.setWidth(5);
```

Comment: Well ScrollView doesnt scroll vertically what radio button size increase. So rest of radio button hide on a view

Comment: you set scrollview inside **android:layout_width="match_parent"           
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"**

Comment: Still no luck with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

Use `radioButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(25, 25));` in your code .

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mActivity);
// you can change the width and height
radioButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(25, 25));
linearLayout.addView(radioButton);
```

**Note**

You can change width、height、and weight in it .

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, weight));
```