# How to increase the size of the radio button circle? (android)

Tags: android, radio-button

I am enlarging it through scale X and scale Y, but Android does not display it completely.

please help me :(

Comment: looks like scaling is the only way... can you give your code for better help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46318853/11002756 does this help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to change the Size of the RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014597/android-how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radiobutton)